# Can I access the keychain on the iPhone with MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, keychain

I have recently started to develop applications for iPhone with MonoTouch and have to store user names and passwords on the phone. I want to use the keychain for this but can't find anything in the MonoTouch documentation about it. Is it possible to use it directly with MonoTouch or will I have to write some C++/C/Objective-C code that uses the keychain and export it to MonoTouch?

Comment: You do know that MonoTouch has probably been banned from the App Store?

Comment: It hasnt been banned at all - they are still approving apps made in MT. They have no reason to have a gripe with MT.

Comment: They are still approving apps made in MT but nobody except Apple knows what will happen when 4.0 hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [current documentation](http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?tlink=root:/MonoTouch-lib), there is no bindings for the keychain.

Your solutions are:

- post a request to Novell for the bindings.
- write a .NET wrapper around the KeyChain function by accessing them through P/Invoke. The [following page](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types) gives you some hint on how to do it. If you need some direction on how to provide an object-oriented wrapper for KeyChain, you can take some inspiration from the [EMKeyChain library](http://extendmac.com/EMKeychain/).